# Can We Tell Which of These Strategies are Dominated?

Tags: game-theory

This is the strategic form for a zero-sum game; it reflects player 1's expectations. I need to reduce this strategic form from 4x4 to 2x2 by eliminating the dominated strategies. 
All the examples I've seen use numbers and I'm struggling in this general case without knowing what a and b are.  I've painted grey the strategies I think are dominated. Can someone confirm or deny this result and explain to me the method for computing this?

[image]

Comment: do you have any information about $a$ and $b$. Perhaps $a,b >0$?

Comment: Yes, a,b are both greater than zero but I don't know if a>b or b>a. I'm dreading that you'll tell me I'm just missing an obvious inequality argument here; I've spent a lot of time looking at those.

Answer (score 0):

here's another go at it.

For player 1, $S_{2}$ weakly dominates $S_{4}$ since $a$ and $b$ strictly positive imply $\frac{b}{4}>0$, $0\geq0$, $\frac{a+b}{4}>0$ and $\frac{a}{4}>0$. Similarly, $S_{1}$ weakly dominates $S_{3}$. This leaves only two surviving actions for player 1: $S_{1}$ and $S_{2}$.

Next, (as you mentioned) for player 2, $S_{2}$ strictly dominates $S_{3}$ since $\frac{b-a}{4}>\frac{-(3a+b)}{4}$ and $0>\frac{-(a+b)}{4}$. $S_{2}$ also dominates $S_{4}$ since $\frac{b-a}{4}>-a$ and $0>\frac{-a}{4}$

Maybe I'm still missing something?

Comment: Thanks for the response. I should have clarified that the values in this table are the payout for player 1; it is a zero-sum game, so player 2 has the same table but with the sign changed.  Do you still stand by your comment about player 2?  I think that S_3 is a worse strategy for player 2 than s_2 since it yields a larger payout for player 1 and, thus, cost player 2 more.